# nsq отправка сообщения

Tags: django, python-2.7

Всем привет
Помогите пожалуйста, учу python django
Мне нужно отправить сообщение на эл.почту в определенное время
Начал учить pynsq но не могу в нем разобраться
Пример кода, отправки простого сообщения

```
def mail(request):
  form = MailForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MailForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            name = form.cleaned_data.get('name')
            descriptions = form.cleaned_data.get('descriptions')
            time = form.cleaned_data.get('time')
            send_mail(name, descriptions, settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, ['info@mail.ru'])
```

Как вызывать pynsq что нужно прописывать?

Comment: A realtime distributed messaging platform http://nsq.io/ - что-то я не понял, причем здесь email. Для асинхронной отправки есть cellery. NSQ - это обмен сообщениями типа json, http. Отправка email в реальном времени что-то не привычное. для рассылок первое время лучше github.com/ui/django-post_office или подобные готовые. Когда будет все понятно "пилите" свой "велосипед" под задачу.

Answer (score 2):

Создать консольную команду в management/commands/sendmail.py с отправкой почты.

По cron (или по планировщику в винде) в нужное время выполнять

```
manage.py sendmail
```